# Angular getting (...)tooltip is not a function with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am trying to incorporate Jquery inside my Angular 8 project using

var $ = require('jquery');

However when I call this method

```
$(MyControl).tooltip({'title': data.text, html:true});
```

I get a **TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function**

My angular.json scripts section looks exactly like this so jquery is declared before the other two

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"             
            ],
```

What is causing this error?

**UPDATE**
Ok this is just wierd
So putting these js files under the styles header in my angular.json it works

```
 "styles": [                       
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

Placing them under the scripts section it doesnt work, removing them completely from the angular.json and they dont work.

Only two places does it work and that is directly in the index.html as CDN or in the styles section.

Is there any rhyme or reason on why this works under styles and not scripts?

Comment: Try with this: `($(MyControl) as any).tooltip({'title': data.text, html:true});`

Comment: Tried that. I also did a console.log($(y)) and I dont even see tooltip as part of the control. I see mouse over, mousehover etc but nothing that says tooltip

Comment: @robert  So this is wierd. this works when placing those js files under the styles section of angular.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a variable called jQuery or $ in the angular component where you want to use jQuery plugin.

```
declare var $: any;
```

**OR**

```
declare var jQuery: any;
```

The *declare* keyword is used for ambient declarations where you want to define a variable that may not have originated from a TypeScript file.

Comment: So this works 
console.log(`jQuery version: ${$.fn.jquery}`); However this still throws and error $(mycontrol).tooltip()

Comment: This  is wierd that it only works when placing the js files under the styles section of my angular.json